# Need help with SQL query

Tags: sql, database

Here are the tables I have:

```
employee
 -id
project
 -id
 -employee_id
role
 -id
 -project_id
 -start_date
 -end_date
role_skill
 -id
 -role_id
 -skill_id

skill
 -id
 -name
```

So basically an Employee hasMany Projects, a Project hasMany roles, a Role hasMany RoleSkills, and a RoleSkill has a Skill

I am trying to query for "Skill1 with at least 10 years of experience and Skill 2 with  at least 3 years of experience"

Where years of experience an employee has for a skill is based on the role's that the employee has that skill listed.

The query to find an employee who has a particular skill is no problem, but how do I "look back" once I know they have the skill to calculate the number of years of experience?

Thanks!

Here's an example of the store procedure that has the current code in it:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeQuerySkill]
    @csvList varchar(400),
    @years int,
    @fudge int,
    @hitAll int = 0
AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @csvLength int
set @csvLength = (select count(*) from SplitCSVStrings(@csvList))

IF @csvLength > 0
BEGIN
    if @hitAll=0 SET @csvLength = 0
    SELECT distinct hits.attribHits as hits, id, last_name+', '+first_name AS emp_name, SUM(CAST(total_experience/12.0 as DECIMAL(5,2))) AS total_exp, labor_grade, title, ptype, @csvList AS pval FROM
        (SELECT e.id, e.last_name, e.first_name, e.labor_grade, e.title, 'skill' AS ptype,
                CASE WHEN r.end_date ='01/01/1901' THEN SUM(datediff(MM,r.start_date, GETDATE())) ELSE SUM(datediff(MM,r.start_date, r.end_date)) END AS total_experience
        FROM [Skillsdb_dev].[dbo].[employee] AS e
        JOIN [Skillsdb_dev].[dbo].[project]             AS prj ON prj.employee_id = e.id
        JOIN [Skillsdb_dev].[dbo].[role]                AS r   ON r.project_id = prj.id
        JOIN [Skillsdb_dev].[dbo].[role_skill]          AS rs  ON rs.role_id = r.id
        JOIN [Skillsdb_dev].[dbo].[skill]               AS s   ON s.id = rs.skill_id
        JOIN SplitCSVStrings(@csvList)            AS CSV ON CSV.val = s.name
        GROUP BY e.id, e.last_name, e.first_name, e.labor_grade, e.title, r.end_date) total_aggregate
    JOIN csvSkillAttribHits(@csvList) AS hits ON hits.empRecId = id
    WHERE total_aggregate.total_experience >= ((@years * 12)-@fudge) AND hits.attribHits >= @csvLength
    GROUP BY id, last_name, first_name, labor_grade, title, ptype,hits.attribHits
    ORDER BY emp_name DESC

END

END
```

This seems to work until I try to add a 2nd parameter in there, which is what the csvList is, so I can search for "Java, C++" for example

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: added current code in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, based on your description I think it should get what you are after.  If not it will get you close...

```
   SELECT e.id, s.name, (r.End_date - r.Start_Date) as 'Experience'
    FROM employee AS e
    INNER JOIN project AS p ON e.id = p.employee_id
    INNER JOIN role AS r ON p.id = r.project_id
    INNER JOIN role_skill AS rs ON rs.role_id = r.id
    INNER JOIN skill as s ON s.id = rs.skill_id
    WHERE s.id = <whatever skill you want to see>
```

Comment: How do I make this give me a result for each skill, if I am passing in more than one skill in an array? In my example, this is the CSVList that will have "Java,C++" in it, so ideall i'd like to get a row back showing years experience in Java, and another row with years experience in C++. You can see my update which shows what I had

Comment: You can make it `WHERE s.id IN (1,2,3)` assuming you want to see skills 1, 2, and 3.  You can also add a `GROUP BY` to the end, with the main field you want to group by then the rest of the fields listed after.

Comment: I was able to get something close to this more or less working, but I had to use a function to split my csvlist since it is string values, not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group on skill_id and sum the difference between project end and start date.

```
select e.id, s.name, sum(p.end_date-p.start_date) experience
from employee e
, project p
, role r
, role_skill rs
, skill s
where e.id = p.employee_id
and p.id = r.project_id
and r.id = rs.role_id
and rs.skill_id = s.id
group by e.id, s.name;
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out the grouping. For my example I posted, I am running this query on a list of parameters. How would I make it give me a result of years experience for each of the skills I am querying on?

Comment: My query would give you the number of days experience (at least, on Oracle, not sure what e.g. MySQL does when subtracting dates). What result does my query give you when run against your data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DATEDIFF function in your WHERE clause to check if the diff between the dates is at least three years.

"...WHERE DATEDIFF(yy,start_date,end_date) >= 3"