# How to search on pairs of values in this SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

I have the following SQL procedure/select statement that I am working on modifying. I derived this from a previous question I had which can be referenced here: [Need help with SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226342/need-help-with-sql-query)

This works pretty good when I do not have the conditional in there checking for years of experience, but I actually want to modify this so that if I have a list passed in `@csvList` and another list of `@csvYears`, then I can pair the values - that is, I can search for `Skill1` with 5 years of experience, and `Skill2` with 3 years of experience.

Can I just do another JOIN on the table of `csvYears`? (The `SplitCSVStrings` function returns a table, and splits the CSV list of values)

So behold the existing code:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeQuerySkill]
    @csvList varchar(400),
    @years int,
    @fudge int,
    @hitAll int = 0
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT last_name, id, name, SUM(Experience ) AS 'YearsExperience'
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT e.last_name, e.id, s.name, CASE WHEN r.end_date ='01/01/1901' THEN MAX(datediff(YY,r.start_date, GETDATE())) ELSE MAX(datediff(YY,r.start_date, r.end_date)) END AS 'Experience'
      FROM employee as e
      INNER JOIN project AS p ON e.id = p.employee_id
      INNER JOIN role AS r ON p.id = r.project_id
      INNER JOIN role_skill AS rs ON rs.role_id = r.id
      INNER JOIN skill AS s ON s.id = rs.skill_id
      JOIN SplitCSVStrings(@csvList)            AS CSV ON CSV.val = s.name

     GROUP BY e.last_name, e.id, s.name, r.end_date
  )  table1    
  WHERE table1.Experience >= @years
  GROUP BY last_name, id, name

  END
END
```

How can I modify this to allow me to search for a different condition for each of the skills? `@csvList` is coming in like "C++, Java" and I want `@years` to come in as `"5, 3"` and the corresponding search to show me people that have 5 years of C++ experience, and 3 years of Java experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to modify the function `SplitCSVStrings` for this to work. Yo should make it so the table that it returns has one extra column indicating the position in the csv. For example, if the parameter is "C++, Java", the result should be:

```
id val
1  C++
2  Java
```

If you do that, then you can modify your query to be like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeQuerySkill]
    @csvList varchar(400),
    @years int,
    @fudge int,
    @hitAll int = 0
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT last_name, id, name, SUM(Experience ) AS 'YearsExperience'
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT e.last_name, e.id, s.name, CASE WHEN r.end_date ='01/01/1901' THEN MAX(datediff(YY,r.start_date, GETDATE())) ELSE MAX(datediff(YY,r.start_date, r.end_date)) END AS 'Experience', CSV2.val Years
      FROM employee as e
      INNER JOIN project AS p ON e.id = p.employee_id
      INNER JOIN role AS r ON p.id = r.project_id
      INNER JOIN role_skill AS rs ON rs.role_id = r.id
      INNER JOIN skill AS s ON s.id = rs.skill_id
      JOIN SplitCSVStrings(@csvList) AS CSV ON CSV.val = s.name
      LEFT JOIN SplitCSVStrings(@years) AS CSV2 ON CSV.id = CSV2.id

     GROUP BY e.last_name, e.id, s.name, r.end_date, CSV2.val
  )  table1    
  WHERE table1.Experience >= years
  GROUP BY last_name, id, name

  END
END
```

In any case, you shoud be careful that the parameters passed in both @csvlist AND @years are the same.

Comment: Is the grouping set up correctly for this? I changed your line to CSV2.val as 'Years' and added 'Years' to the group by and still couldnt get it quite working

Comment: you are right, sorry, the grouping was wrong. I corrected it now, so it should work